# What is the correct term to describe literary works that are only partly fictional?

Tags: literature

I'm trying to find the correct English word to describe a body of literature that is fiction in essence, but all background like places, circumstances, organizations, etc. is actually borrowed from the real world. Generally, we broadly categorize the work into fiction (such as Harry Potter, LOTR, etc.) and non-fiction (self-help and financial books, psychology, history, etc).

However, bordering between the two, there are fictional books that have a background in the real world. Below are two examples:

1. Dan Brown's *Da Vinci Code*: Brown's fiction generally involve a rich background of art, architecture, history, etc.. of the REAL world and claimed as actual facts in the book itself. In this novel, Brown describes in vivid details, a religious organization called *Opus Dei* and a secret society called *priory of sion* that actually exists since the time of Da Vinci.
2. John Grisham's *The Testament*: Grisham is another author who writes pure fiction, but the background is filled with intricate details about the US legal system and FBI in the real world.

Since they are not pure fiction, what is the right term to define these novels? Semi-fiction or part-fiction seems logical, but I don't see them used anywhere. The much popularized term science fiction is good, but doesn't come handy in this situation.

Comment: What term does [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction) use?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Wikipedia is an unofficial source at best. WRT Da Vinci code, *Conspiracy Fiction* is used, but that describes only one aspect of that particular book. I want to know the term for general broader categorization of "semi fictional" books.

Comment: "Fiction" is, I think, the term you're looking for.  The Da Vinci code might be argued to be, in part, "historical fiction", but that doesn't fit it as a whole.

Comment: These are fictional works. The author draws on real life to ease the belief of the reader without having to construct an entire universe for the purpose of telling a story.

Comment: @HotLicks I take Fiction to mean the *invented* body of literature. Whilst such literature is there in Da Vinci code, the theme of that novel is actually the *non invented* literature (ie. Christ's secrets, the priory, etc.). Hence I'm not sure it can be called Fiction.

Comment: @IanMcDonald In DaVinci Code, the part that the author "draws on" from the real world, is actually the main theme of the novel.

Comment: The Da Vinci Code is, in fact, entirely fictional (there was a court case in which Brown testified to that effect). Throwing in names and places may make it *plausible* (depending on the reader) but does not make it any more factual than 'Saving Private Ryan' (which I understand was also meticulously researched).

Comment: A related term, which doesn't fit the entirely fictional *Code*, is "roman à clef" - a novel about real life but with a veneer of fiction to disguise the characters and situations.

Comment: There is a medium that falls somewhere between truth and fiction which could be called *20th century history according to Hollywood*.

Comment: @WS2 That is history in every age, from the Pharaohs down.

Comment: @StoneyB In fairness, it isn't just Hollywood. At a relatively young age (in the 1950s) I did puzzle over the fact that the Japanese would actually ask their British captives how to build a bridge?

Comment: @WS2 The basic rule in dealing with sources is that the more coherent it is, and the more sense it makes, the more likely it is to be a fictional construction. And it ain't just primary sources you have to approach with a deconstructionist wrecking-ball.

Comment: Wikipedia is a lot better than any source you've mentioned. I was trying to point out (unsuccessfully, it would appear) that evidences of research are considered proper in questions on ELU. _Semi-fiction_ is listed if not defined at Dictionary.com. There are quite a few instances of it on the internet; it is used in the expected way. Time to close-vote.

Comment: Any book which either assumes common law of physics or the existence of human beings is “only partly fictional”, since physics and humans are facts. And even those which modify laws of nature and species of characters tend to still contain a factual core which readers can connect with. I'd argue that there is no such thing as a completely and fictional work with no foundation in facts, so any book which is a mixture of facts and fiction unless it's purely factual.

Comment: @WS2  *Bridge on the river Kwai*, may not have been a true story, nor terribly realistic,  but it was still a good film!

Comment: @Mari-LouA A book that is well worth reading is *The Colonel of Tamarkan* . Julie Summers tells the story as she received it from her grandfather Philip Toosey, who was the real British officer in charge of the bridge building. Though Alec Guiness won an Oscar for his portrayal of 'Colonel Nicholson' in *The Bridge on the River Kwai*, his role, she says 'bore scant resemblance to the facts'.

Comment: @MvG Terry Pratchet's Discworld novels come close. Also anything by Jeffrey Archer, no, sorry, they're just implausible!

Comment: @BoldBen, while the world of discworld is deviating from ours in a number of ways, it's characters tend to be so enjoyable because quite often they expose all to familiar behaviour, albeit exaggerated. Regarding Dan Brown mentioned in the original question, I recently found https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DanBrowned although I'm not sure whether TV Tropes has sufficient impact to coin that term for a broader audience, and it's not a noun either so not exactly an answer to this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The works you cite are wholly fictional.  Being well-researched and more plausible than, say, a sci-fi yarn or Harry Potter doesn't change that.

If you were looking to invent a term, some that might apply include **gritty** (generally implies more realism than average, although that wouldn't apply to a well-researched comedy book), or even **[realistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction#Realistic_fiction)**.

Semi-fictional could describe a genre that in ad copy might say "Based on actual events" or "Ripped from the headlines" (at least per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction#Semi_fiction) definition), but neither of the works cited seem to fit into that category.

Answer (score 8):

Fiction is fiction. Different eras and different audiences vary widely in the sort of background they demand, but every storyteller has to supply some measure of what W.S. Gilbert called "merely corroborative detail intended to provide artistic verisimilitude to an otherwise bald and unconvincing narrative." Verisimilitude may reside in familiar quotidian detail or romantic "history" or in the depiction of motive and mental states; but without some such detail there's no framework to set the story in and no identifiable connection with the reader's own experience.

Answer (score 7):

**Semi-fiction** and **semi-fictional** don't seem to be unusual terms.  I would use them.

> Semi-fiction is fiction implementing a great deal of non-fiction, for example: a fictional depiction "based on a true story", or a fictionalized account, or a reconstructed biography.
>   Often, even when the author claims the story is true, there may be significant additions and subtractions from the true story to make it more suitable for storytelling.
>   One such example would be Tim O'Brien's The Things They Carried. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction#Semi-fiction)

from Google Books:

- While **semi-fictional** text can emerge in a directed way, we also highlight...
- Gathered here are some of Dreiser's best pieces of short fiction and **semi-fiction**.
- Metamorphosis: A Small Piece of **Semi-fiction**.
- The Retreat - A **Semi-Fictional** Memoir Exploring Common ...
- It is in any case a **semi-fictional** genre, novelistic in its own way.

Comment: That description doesn't really fit Da Vinci Code.

Comment: Don't know *The Things They Carried*, but this makes me think of *Schindler's Ark* which is very much about telling the story of a historic person, but still deviated from historic facts for dramaturgic reasons, e.g. by combining several historic persons into a single character of the story. Compared to this, the works cited in the question are certainly purely fictional.

Comment: [Non-fiction novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fiction_novel) is another term that very much doesn't apply to the Da Vinci Code, although Wikipedia mentions Truman Capote's In Cold Blood, André Breton's Nadja, and other examples. Basically, using novelistic techniques to tell a factual story.

Answer (score 6):

The Da Vinci Code is a [secret history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_history).

> Secret history is ... used to describe a type or genre of fiction which portrays a substantially different motivation or backstory from established historical events.

John Grisham's books (at least the ones I've read) are not secret histories. Most fiction (unlike *Harry Potter, LOTR*) is set in the real world, and accurately depicting certain elements from the real world as background is very common in fiction. John Grisham's thrillers often go into details of the law and the legal profession more extensively than most fiction about lawyers, but this is just one point on a continuum, and I don't know of a special word for this.

Comment: _Harry Potter_ is set in (a fictional part of) the real world. Some parts of it are even set in dreary suburbian Surrey, or on the tube. _LOTR_ claims to be set in the real world—just a very long time ago—though that’s obviously demonstrably not. _A Song of Fire and Ice_ or the _Dune_ books are examples of literary works set entirely in wholly fictional worlds.

Answer (score 2):

As other answerers have stated, the works you list are entirely fictional.  Fiction, in general, borrows from the real world.  I would challenge you to name a single work of fiction that borrows nothing from the real world.

That said,

> **Creative nonfiction** (also known as **literary nonfiction** or **narrative nonfiction**) is a genre of writing that uses literary styles and techniques to create factually accurate narratives.

[Source.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_nonfiction)

Answer (score 1):

How about **faction**?

noun, Informal.

1. a form of writing or film making that treats real people or events as if they were fictional or uses them as an integral part of a fictional account.
2. a novel, film, play, or other presentation in this form.

Origin
1965-70; blend of fact and fiction

[ I know - it's a horrible portmanteau. ]

Answer (score 1):

Probably just historical fiction or realistic fiction.
I'm not sure there is a genre name for being highly detailed.
After all, most fiction is set roughly in the "real world" the fiction that is set in purely make believe worlds is its own genre, namely fantasy. Being set in a plausible real world setting isn't a genre set apart from mainstream fiction.

Comment: Welcome, Aaron. Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and see if you can [improve this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands now, this sounds like unsubstantiated opinion - which is not what we're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is not a completely true account is fiction.

Maybe there is some sub genre of fiction (things like historical fiction, for example--fictional stories that take place in a historically accurate setting) that would satisfy you but, there's no "almost fiction." It's simply true or not true.

Comment: So a history book with a mistake in it (and I bet many of them do have, in tiny details or interpretation) should be classed under 'fiction'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Certainly a substantial fraction of "history" is fiction.

Comment: No account of anything in the history of humankind has ever been a “completely true account”. There is no such thing. Such a basic dichotomy between fiction and non-fiction makes absolutely no sense and is just not true.

Comment: On this stack you could say "Up is the opposite of down" and people would fight you. Clearly life involves shades of grey. Dictionaries do not. Fiction and non-fiction are the two broadest categories of literature. One means "all of this is real" and the other means "this is not all necessarily real."

Comment: perhaps a better way of putting it is that the writer of non-fiction *aims* to provide a completely true account, whereas the writer of fiction does not.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of history, *historic fiction* might fit your description.

Answer (score 0):

> What about **[Roman à clef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_%C3%A0_clef).**

- a novel in which real persons or actual events figure under disguise. ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roman%20%C3%A0%20clef))

> French for novel with a key, is a **novel about real life, overlaid with
>   a façade of fiction**. The fictitious names in the novel represent real
>   people, and the "key" is the relationship between the nonfiction and
>   the fiction.

(Wiki)

Answer (score 0):

***Pseudo-fiction*** is a coined term for this genre but it is not well-established yet. The term is also used to describe Dan Brown's *The DaVinci Code* in various reviews.

> A plethora of books/booklets have come out in response to Brown’s work of pseudo-fiction (I say that because he has come to believe his own fiction, and clearly the book is intended to communicate an underlying matrix of “facts” even while presenting them in an allegedly fictional milieu)...
>
> <sub>[[www.aomin.org]](http://www.aomin.org/aoblog/index.php/2004/11/19/111904-dan-brown-and-his-fiction-of-renown/)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> I read Dan Brown's claim of fiction as a double negative. The first negative is the "fact" page which has very little basis in fact. The second negative is the claim that Dan Brown intended to write fiction. He has said on an ABC interview that if he had written the book as non-fiction he would have changed none of the details of the conspiracy and historical interpretation.
>
> This makes it hard to classify the genre of *DaCode*, but I propose we create a new genre for *DaCode* and its ilk: pseudo-fiction. **A pseudo-fiction is "false-false." It is false fiction; which means, according to the rule of double negative, it is non-fiction. Note that I did not say it was true or fact.** We have no such category when it comes to literature, unless you include reference materials. However, reference materials and non-fiction works are subject to scrutiny.
>
> **The point of proposing the "pseudo-fiction" genre is to get around the claim of Brown and others that *DaCode* is "just fiction." It isn't fair to simply claim that something is fiction when it pretends to be more.**
>
> <sub>[writtenwithoutink.blogspot.ca](http://writtenwithoutink.blogspot.ca/2006/05/pseudo-fiction.html)</sub>

The term appears in *[goodreads.com](http://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/pseudo-fiction)* as well but there are a few books listed. A notable book mentioned is *The Boy in the Striped Pajamas* which is based on historical events (that are not actually documented) but also criticized as being unrealistic. Another genre mentioned is *historical fiction* for this book.

Another book that is mentioned as a *pseudo-fiction* is Daniel Defoe's *A Journal of the Plague Year* which is a fictionalised account of one man's experiences of the year 1665, in which the Great Plague struck the city of London.<sup>[[wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Journal_of_the_Plague_Year)</sup>

The genre is mentioned in the book N*ew Perspectives on Robert Graves* (edited by Patrick J. Quinn) when being compared to Graves' work:

[image]

Comment: "Pseudo-fiction" is a ridiculous term to use, since the stuff is clearly, purely fiction.  "Pseudo-fact" may be a better term.  (But then all fiction is "pseudo-fact".)

Comment: There is a similar term : [*pseudo-documentary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-documentary)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the genre you want is "Docufiction" or "Historical Fiction".

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the query is long gone, but have you looked into "Magical Realism"? The works of Colombian writer Gabriel Garcia Marquez (Love in the time of Cholera, One Hundred Years of Solitude) are the example of this.

Comment: 'Magical realism' is a genre in literature (and other forms of art), not a word you can use to describe any work of (semi-)fiction. And I don't see how the link is relevant to this question/answer at all. If it were linking to a smaller site I would have thought it could be spam. I have removed it. Please take our [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. Welcome to ELU :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is also the rather recent term [*non-fiction novel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fiction_novel).

From Wikipedia:

> The non-fiction novel is a literary genre which, broadly speaking, depicts real historical figures and actual events woven together with fictitious conversations and uses the storytelling techniques of fiction
> ...
> The genre goes back at least as far as André Breton's Nadja (1928) and several books by the Czech writer Vítězslav Nezval, such as Ulice Git-le-coeur (1936). One of the early English books in the genre is Rebecca West's Black Lamb and Grey Falcon (1941).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fiction_novel) Jim Bishop's The Glass Crutch (1945) was advertised as "one of the most unusual best-sellers ever published—a non-fiction novel."[2](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/97/12/28/home/capote-interview.html) Perhaps the most influential nonfiction novel of the twentieth century was John Hersey's Hiroshima (1946).[3] Scholar David Schmid writes that "many American writers during the post-World War II period, including Joan Didion, Truman Capote, and Norman Mailer, [chose] to follow Hersey’s lead."

Truman Capote's account of the Clutter murders of 1959, *In Cold Blood*, is a prime example of this genre. The writer George Plimpton interviewed Capote on this for an article in The New York Times that he titled "[The Story Behind a Nonfiction Novel](https://archive.nytimes.com/www.nytimes.com/books/97/12/28/home/capote-interview.html)"; he opens this way:

> In Cold Blood" is remarkable for its objectivity--nowhere, despite his involvement, does the author intrude. In the following interview, done a few weeks ago, Truman Capote presents his own views on the case, its principals, and in particular he discusses the new literary art form which he calls the nonfiction novel...

Answer (score 0):

In Latin American literature criticism, there is the accepted "Historical fiction" of which originate in modern form with the works of Walter Scott and James Fenimore Cooper. In these, the protagonist(s) were set in a specific, historically realist context, and may feature a cameo of an historically important person, but the main thrust of the narrative is fictional (i.e., without historical corroboration).

There is also a new type of historical fiction defined by Seymour Menton as "New Historical Fiction" which go against some of the main descriptors. While it is still set in a specific, historically realist context, the protagonist tend to be a main historical figure. The plot must therefore be careful to not only be historically accurate in context, but historically accurate about the main events. The fictional parts are left to "fill in the gaps" between historically known events, and help explain what is otherwise historical speculation, such as a person's motivation. One example of this is Martín Caparrós's *Ansay ó los infortunios de la gloria*, a novel which directly quotes extensively from Ansay's memoirs as well as from other primary sources related to Argentina's struggle for independence in 1810-1820 AD. The purpose of the novel is to try and understand what motivated this Spanish colonel to chose to oppose the fight for independence.

With this parameter gone (i.e., the main character is not a historical figure) for what constitutes a traditional historical fiction, it is only a matter of time for some other work to break the time barrier (historical fiction is set at least a generation prior, and/or historical characters not alive). With enough examples, it will probably get a new name, like "docu-fiction".